# Running Ruby from usr/bin instead of usr/local/bin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, installation

So I was following the steps on [Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) to get ruby on rails setup on my machine. After compiling and installing, I used the `which ruby` command to double check it installed in the right place. It did not. I was able to install the Rails and MySQL gems though, but both POW and localhost:3000 don't work.

Is there anything wrong with having it in the usr/bin directory instead of usr/local/bin? My usr/local/bin is practically empty, but usr/bin has a ton of files in it.

**Edit:** I reinstalled ruby to usr/local/bin but now Rails won't install. Is it a problem that it's already installed in usr/bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to get rails installed in the correct spot. I had to change the line in my .profile to `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` and then do a `sudo gem update --system` after installing rubygems before rails could actually be installed.

RVM and Homebrew did not help at all.

**EDIT:** Since people have a problem with this answer, I'm giving an update. I have since installed RVM and am liking it, but only because I have a friend I ask all my questions to, as RVM is really confusing if you're not used to doing a lot on the command line. I needed help from him to install it because I didn't have any of the bash files, and thought they were hiding somewhere. If you're missing the bash files, just create them yourself. This took a long time to get working, but now I apparently have it setup right.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that recommends installing from source as the first option instead of a last-resort fallback is probably bad advice. It's better to install using a package manager like [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) both of which have current versions of Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

MacPorts installs everything in `/opt` specifically to avoid conflict with system files. From time to time Apple will distribute an update that patches `ruby` and this can mess up anything you have in the way of dependencies if you've been using a modified `/usr/bin/ruby`. Generally the system ruby is supposed to be left as-is.

You can replace the "compile ruby" step with an installer like that and save yourself a lot of trouble in the future. Just be sure to have `/opt/local/bin` as one of the first items in your `PATH` just as you would for other solutions.

Since installing Ruby and Rails and some kind of database can be a confusing process, it seems like there should be a meta-installer to help you through the process.

Comment: Do you have any resources for using homebrew to install rails? The tutorials I'm finding don't work...

Answer (score 1):

That page is a few years old. The current best practice for Mac and Linux is to use [rvm](https://rvm.io). You can see, [even Hivelogic uses rvm now](http://hivelogic.com/articles/setup-guide-rails-stack-with-passenger-rvm-bundler-apache-and-mysql-on-ubun/) (though I'm not sure how I feel about installing it system wide).

Comment: RVM installed it in the wrong place... `/Users/Michele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/bin/ruby` instead of usr/local/bin ??

Comment: Now my ruby is running out of there instead of usr/local/bin =( This is so complicated.

Comment: RVM installs locally, that is where it should be.

Comment: Everything I've seen says to install ruby into usr/local/bin. What's the positive of installing it in my Home directory?

Comment: Installing in your home directory means you only affect yourself. (You can install it as superuser, which they do at that link, but I'd feel uncomfortable doing that) The entire thing is contained within a folder in your home dir, so you can remove it by just wiping out that dir, for instance. You don't have to worry about clobbering your system Ruby, which other things in your Mac will rely on. In other words, it doesn't affect your system at all, you just adjust your $PATH to look locally first, so your shell session is the only thing affected.